# Delphi - E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Im new to Delphi, trying to make debug on a project which is implemented years ago. My ide is Delphi 2010 and the code with error;

```
function DrawTextExW(hDC: HDC; lpString: PWideChar; nCount: Integer; var lpRect:
TRect; uFormat: UINT; dtp: PDRAWTEXTPARAMS): Integer;

const
   MAX_STATIC_BUFFER = 8192;
const
   STATIC_BUFFER_LEN: integer = 8192;
const
   DT_PREFIXONLY = $00200000;

var
...
  tm: TTextMetricA;
...

begin
  ...

  GetTextMetrics(hDC, tm);    //Error Line
  if (uFormat and DT_EXTERNALLEADING) = DT_EXTERNALLEADING then
    lh := tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading
  else
    lh := tm.tmHeight;

  ...
end
```

Getting "[DCC Error] ElVCLUtils.pas(3555): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical" error in that line. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: The compiler tells you exactly what's wrong with the code. Identify the var parameter, and then check the types of the actual and formal parameters in question. You'll see they don't match.

Comment: Have you considered whether this function even needs to exist anymore? `DrawTextExW` is already provided by the OS. Maybe your project comes from a time when you were targeting Ansi versions of Windows, like Windows 98. Those versions aren't supported by Microsoft or Embarcadero, so maybe you don't need to support them, either. Then you could delete all this code instead of fixing it.

Comment: Rob, you must be right about support, the project coming before christ :) I will write project again in a different platform so trying to read and understanding the algorithm. Serg's answer is enough for a quick fix. thanks for your answer ;)

Answer (score 7):

You should use either

```
var
...
  tm: TTextMetric;
...

begin
  ...

  GetTextMetrics(hDC, tm);
```

or

```
var
...
  tm: TTextMetricA;
...

begin
  ...

  GetTextMetricsA(hDC, tm);
```

the first version is preferable.

Comment: +1, you could add why the first version is preferrable though

Comment: @Smasher - because there is no need to use ANSI versions of the function/structure. `GetTextMetricsA` & `TTextMetricA` makes code less readable and supportable.

Comment: yes, I am aware of that. I just thought it would make your answer more complete if you add the argument supporting your statement :)